# SQL query data to cshtml

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, razor, ado.net

I'm not very good but I'm trying. I think there is something I don't understand somewhere...
I'm trying to get statistique from a DB like how many row got "X". Look simple. I know the SQL statement for it. There is a lot of walkthrough around. But I don't know how to make it appear on a page.

```
if(!Request.QueryString["RNum"].IsEmpty() ) {

   searchTerm = Request.QueryString["RNum"];
 selectCommand2 = "SELECT COUNT(NoEmpl) FROM DTool Where NoEmpl = @0";
}
var Count = db.QueryValue(selectCommand2, searchTerm);
```

With a submit button to send the query how can I make it appear on a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try this

```
searchTerm = Request.QueryString["RNum"];
string sqlSelect = "SELECT COUNT(NoEmpl) FROM DTool Where NoEmpl= @NoEmpl";

SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectString);
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, sqlConnection);

// Set SqlDbType based on your DB column Data-Type 
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@NoEmpl", System.Data.SqlDbType.Varcahr);


 sqlCommand.Parameters["@NoEmpl"].Value = searchTerm ;
```

OR

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();      
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
        "SELECT COUNT(NoEmpl) FROM DTool Where NoEmpl= @NoEmpl", connection))
        {
        //
        // Add new SqlParameter to the command.
        //
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NoEmpl", searchTerm ));
        //
        // Read in the SELECT results.
        //
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        //read here
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do I need to write on cshtml to see the result? Do I have to make a Foreach, a webgrid? @something?